# Error message in view file

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, yii-routing

I'm new in Yii Framework. I want to check user exists or not with ajax.

**view file**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $baseUrl;?>/persons/login" role="form"><br>
    <div style="display: block;margin-left:14%">
        <div>İstifadəçi adı</div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="istiad" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" tabindex="1">
        </div>
        <div>Parol</div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" name="parol" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" maxlength="20" tabindex="2"><br>
        </div>
        <?=CHtml::button('daxil ol', ['submit'=>['persons/login', 'i'=>1]]); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### EDIT

[error must looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUIW1.png)

how can i do this ?
 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you have added rule for unique in your model then just do

Enable Ajax validation in _form.php file

```
  <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'person-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'      => true,
        )
    ));
    ?>
```

In you controller actionCreate() and actionUpdate() Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed

```
 $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

Answer (score 1):

add below line in your model class inside path/to/protected/models/modelname.php `array('username', 'unique','on'=>'insert', 'message'=>'Username already exists'),` in the `public function rules() { }` function. Here modelname in indicates your corresponding model file name.

If you want to show the error text to be shown without page load enable ajax submission like below in _form.php/corresponding form page

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>
```